# can`t call setState. Помогите пожалуйста. Не могу убрать эту ошибку

Tags: reactjs

есть код. И есть ошибка при выполнении логики. Опишу её в кратце. Есть сайт, с фильмами. По нажатию на название фильма, я перебираю бд нахожу соответствие и передаю параметры в функцию которая перезаписывает this.state. В чём ошибка. Когда нажимаю на название фильма, вылезает такое противное сообщение в консоли. Что делать, не представляю. Пересмотрел много примеров в сети, всё одинаковое, кроме параметров естественно. Но результат разный. Подскажите пожалуйста, как с этим справится?
[image: Класс компонент]
[image: Класс с рендером]
[image: ошибка]

Comment: Сократите пример до минимального и пишите код текстом, а не скриншотами. Ошибка означает что во время вызова сетСтейта компонент ещё не был отрендерен*.

Comment: если что, там два разных скрина, просто удачно слились воедино. То что ошибка означает я знаю. Но я не могу понять почему она приходит. Так как компонент был отрендерен.

Comment: @MaxKozlov Ваши скриншоты никто разглядывать не будет. опубликуйте код в виде текста.